# In angular2 how can I do a select list using ngModel

Tags: angular

In angular2 how can I do a select  list using ngModel

I'm using the latest angular2 libraries.

**My current attempt:**

```
 <select class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0" id="County" name="county" [(ngModel)]="county">
                <option>Filter by County</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of counties" value="" [value]="item.county"  placeholder="Search by County">{{item.county}}</option>
              </select>
```

**Error I get:**

> zone.js?1477842549055:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse
>   errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of
>   'select'. ("       ][(ngModel)]="county">

Comment: Did you add the `FormsModule` to `imports: [...]` in `@NgModule()`?

Comment: cheers - that what it

Comment: Also, remove `value=""`.

Comment: Weird, because the only way it worked for me is if I used "[ngValue]" instead of "[value]" in the option.

Answer (score 2):

Have you imported the **FormsModule** in your App Module?

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

This should work when using `ngModel` in any input/select element.

And the next thing, 
`[value]="item.county"` in option should be same as `[(ngModel)]="county"` in select tag.

```
<select class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-md-2 col-md-offset-0" id="County" name="county" [(ngModel)]="county">
            <option>Filter by County</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of counties" value="" [value]="item"  placeholder="Search by County">{{item.county}}</option>
          </select>
```

i.e. the ngModel value should match the value in option.

Answer (score 0):

You should import *FormsModule* in your module,
check out [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/PF6ShKovRRDiCBIEmK2Q?p=preview)

`<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"  (ngModelChange)="selectedValue=$event;">
      <option *ngFor="let item of _types | enumKeyValuelist;" [value]="item.key">{{item.value}}</option>
    </select>`